# CXF project throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/NotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf

im a beginer in CXF Webservice. when i createde my first WS project it through an exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/NotFoundException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:129) ~[spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isLiteConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:131) ~[spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:90) ~[spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:274) ~[spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254) ~[spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609) ~[spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) ~[spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381) ~[spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293) ~[spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Mar 11, 2014 4:51:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/NotFoundException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isLiteConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:90)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:274)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 24 more
```

i have already added javax.ws.rs.jar file into the classpath but getting the same error.

your help would be greatly appreciable.

Comment: You need to put that jar in your web-inf/lib and redeploy it

Comment: This should help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18064033/2549021

Comment: is cxf2.7.10 version not supported with spring 4.0.0?

Comment: If you are don't use cxf-jms transport, cxf-2.7.10 can work with Sping 4.0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had solved this issue by adding javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10 jar

Comment: This version doesn't have the following class: "javax.ws.rs.MessageProcessingException" ; Which version of javax.ws.rs-api should I use?

Comment: With m10 it works, thank you! I used this link to download: http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar